# TensorFlow Lite converter: 'Convert concrete functions' throws error in official tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to convert a custom function into a TF Lite model, using from_concrete_functions(). To get acquainted with this I read through the documentation but I am not able to execute the example code from the TF website (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#convert_concrete_functions_).

Example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Create a model using low-level tf.* APIs
class Squared(tf.Module):
  @tf.function
  def __call__(self, x):
    return tf.square(x)
model = Squared()
# (ro run your model) result = Squared(5.0) # This prints "25.0"
# (to generate a SavedModel) tf.saved_model.save(model, "saved_model_tf_dir")
concrete_func = model.__call__.get_concrete_function()

# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func],
                                                            model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

When executing the line "concrete_func = model.__call__.get_concrete_function()" an error is thrown: TypeError: tf____call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

I tried TF 2.3, 2.4 and a Google Colab notebook, which all give them same error. What am I missing and how could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RoXvm7KbORlw_VsAPIzfhzps7yvn_PJP?usp=sharing) to see the usage. Also the documentation has been updated. Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#convert_concrete_functions_).

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, seems like the key is to define the input signature in the @tf.function. Documentation is indeed updated and works now without errors

Answer (score 0):

The concrete function API takes two arguments since TensorFlow 2.7 versions. In the earlier versions, you should just pass the first argument only. Sorry for that and the official guide should be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I now understand that I should only give the concrete_func and not the model to the converter. However, my question was about the line before, where I am still confused. According to the guide get_concrete_function() should take zero arguments but is asking for one in the error.